# Who first promoted the idea that competition leads to a better economy?

Tags: reference-request, history-economic-thought, history, philosophy-of-economics, free-market

Who first promoted the the idea that [competition](https://wiki.mises.org/wiki/Competition) leads to a better economy?

Comment: Can you please define "economist"? Do we count the pilosophers of old (like Adam Smith) as economists?

Comment: @Giskard Yes, philosophers included

Comment: I will edit the question so instead of "Which economist" it will read "Who".

Comment: Interesting question. I have no idea but did some online research. It seems the benefits of competition were discussed at least as early as [Hesiod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesiod) who [highlighted](https://ideasofeconomists.com/2018/06/21/the-first-economist-hesiod-and-the-problem-of-scarcity/) the benefits of competition (called "good conflict" by him) for economic growth and relieving the basic problem of scarcity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Huerta de Soto, Jesús](https://www.jesushuertadesoto.com/articles/articles-in-english/juan-de-mariana-and-the-spanish-scholastics/). “[Biography of Juan de Mariana: The Influence of the Spanish Scholastics (1536-1624)](https://mises.org/library/biography-juan-de-mariana-influence-spanish-scholastics-1536-1624).” Article. *Mises Institute* (blog), August 1, 2007:

> the Spanish scholastics were the first ones to introduce the dynamic concept of competition (in Latin *concurrentium*), which is best understood as a process of rivalry among entrepreneurs. For instance, **Jeronimo Castillo de Bovadilla** (1547 ?) wrote that "prices will go down as a result of the abundance, rivalry (*emulacion*), and competition (*concurrencia*) among the sellers."

Comment: Not sure why you think this is the *first* instance. In [their comment](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52168/who-first-promoted-the-idea-that-competition-leads-to-a-better-economy#comment84937_52168) AKdemy cites a source that is two millenia older.

Comment: @Giskard Rothbard ([_Austrian Perspective on the History of Economic Thought_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5391) vol. 1, §1.3) didn't consider Hesiod among the "‘economists’ in the modern sense".

Comment: The requirement that the thinker should be an economist is not in your question, [you specifically write](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52168/who-first-promoted-the-idea-that-competition-leads-to-a-better-economy/57033?noredirect=1#comment84735_52168) "*philosophers included*"